# Core Image slow rendering

Tags: ios, swift, rendering, glkview

I created test application with ViewController, GLKView and UISlider. 
Slider change value in selected filter. Rendering image very slow. 
What's wrong with my code?

Test class of GLKview:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage
import GLKit

class CustomGLView: GLKView {
    //test filters 
    let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")!
    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
    let ciContext:CIContext

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        let glContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        ciContext = CIContext(
            eaglContext: glContext!,
            options: [
                kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()
            ]
        )
        super.init(frame: frame, context: glContext!)
        enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let glContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        ciContext = CIContext(
            eaglContext: glContext!,
            options: [
                kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()
            ]
        )
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        context = glContext!
        enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
    }

      var inputImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            inputCIImage = inputImage.map { CIImage(image: $0)! }
        }
    }

     var blurRadius: Float = 0 {
        didSet {
            blurFilter.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var inputCIImage: CIImage? {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let inputCIImage = inputCIImage {
            clampFilter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            blurFilter.setValue(clampFilter.outputImage!, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: drawableWidth, height: drawableHeight)
            ciContext.draw(blurFilter.outputImage!, in: rect, from: inputCIImage.extent)
        }
    } 
}
```

How I change value in CIFilter:

```
import UIKit
import GLKit
import CoreImage

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        //image
         let imageOriginal = UIImage(named: "pic_2")
         //my GLKView
        @IBOutlet weak var glView: CustomGLView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                //test image
                self.glView.inputImage = self.imageOriginal

            }

        @IBAction func mySlider(_ sender: UISlider) {

                self.glView.blurRadius = sender.value
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you testing on device or simulator?

Comment: Device. In simulator always slow.

Comment: yes because device is hardware accelerated, sim no

Comment: Hello @Metman , i have found same issue while using CIFilter , have you solved above issue and how ?

Comment: Hello @GOPAL VASANI. Just resize image for rendering. When rendering will done, apply changes to original image. I used one CIContext for all.

Comment: Hey @Metman even i used only one  CIContext For all Filters , but still it takes time , i want to show you my code , where i can contact you . ?

Comment: I have the same question. The Accelerate framework and vImage is much faster, so I might just rewrite all my apps using vImage. But it doesn’t really explain why CoreImage is so slow on M1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a `CIImage` from `UIImage` may require extra time to copy the image data from memory to GPU memory. Try loading your image into a GPU texture and then creating a `CIImage` backed by this texture using `CIImage(texture:size:flipped:colorSpace:)`

Make sure you're only creating the texture once, not at the start of every `draw(_:)`.

You could also try:

- Making sure the blur radius isn't too large. A gaussian blur is an expensive operation and it will take longer the greater the blur radius.
- Using a smaller image. If you need larger images, you may want to scale the image down first, apply the blur, and then scale back up (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_performance/ci_performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH10-SW2) for an explanation). Halving the width and height will reduce the number of pixels by a factor of 4.
- `UISlider` will change at a rate of 60 per second. Reducing the frame rate to 30 fps will give you double the time to render each image.